# Bootstrap Reduced Font Size

Tags: asp.net, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m building an intranet application and I will be using bootstrap. My app will have several bootstrap classes, like nav, jumbotron, alerts, buttons, tables, etc.

All the site will use small font, so is there a way to set bootstrap or HTML to use the small font all around without the need to put `small` keyword to all bootstrap classes ?

OBS: Preferably without changing the bootstrap.css or .js files.

Comment: Did you look into [Bootstrap Themeroller](http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/)?

Comment: Looking at.. Seens can be done...